# C# trace https soap requests?

Tags: c#, soap, https, trace

I have a C# app that is sending soap requests over an https channel. Is there any way I can add tracing to just dump every request into a log file? I am getting an error, so im not sure if what I am sending is proper.

Comment: How are you sending SOAP requests? If you use WCF, there's built-in tracing...

Comment: No WCF. I am using the SoapHttpClientProtocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), the HTTP Debugging proxy.

It works with SSL if you [enable it properly](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp).